# Delay by "$z$" in matlab simulink

Tags: matlab

I have a simple question

How could one implement the $z$ or $z^2$ in simulink? The $z^{-2}$ could be implemented by Variable Integer Delay block, but what about $z^2$?

Comment: A z block is acausal.  It effectively advances instead of delays the discrete signal by one sample.  A z^2 block advances it by 2 samples.  I think MATLAB doesn't let you do that.

Comment: you are write and that what I want to do. but are you sure that Matlab don't allow that?

Comment: Related: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19660/is-it-possible-to-design-noncausal-filters-in-matlab - as @MattL points out: "Non-causal FIR filters can always be implemented by appropriate buffering of the input signal and delaying the output signal."