# Using Zero-Phase Anti-Causal Filters in Real-Time Embedded Systems

Tags: filters, digital-communications, digital-filters, causality, embedded-systems

Wanted to know the feasibility and usefulness of implementing Zero-Phase Anti-Causal filters such as those mentioned [at this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/anti-causal-zero-phase-filter-implementation.html) in modern embedded signal processing applications given the advancement of devices on which these applications are now running, resource wise it should not be difficult to implement.

I.e., something like Matlab's `filtfilt`, as opposed to a typical causal IIR filter (picture from [the same page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/anti-causal-zero-phase-filter-implementation.html)):

[image]

The question I want to ask is that if it they are indeed used in practical systems with the advantage of zero-phase distortions or are there other variables in play as well due to which the traditional causal FIR filters are still preferred if non-linear phase distortion is not acceptable?

Comment: Your question seems to be mixing the meanings of "anti-causal filter".  Traditionally, FIR filters are usually symmetric around the midpoint, and are traditionally designed using a filter that's symmetric around zero that is then just translated until it is causal.  In a tradition that makes _me_ want to chew nails, these are often _called_ "non-causal".  They have a _linear_ -- **not zero** phase response when used in real time, but the phase delays in the system can be easily lined up.  Is this what you mean when you say "anti-causal"?

Comment: @TimWescott, sorry If the question wording caused any confusion. "In a tradition that makes me want to chew nails, these are often called "non-causal"" I believe when the FIR filter has been translated then it is no longer "non-causal". However when I used the term 'anti-causal' in the question I referred to the technique shown here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/anti-causal-zero-phase-filter-implementation.html

Comment: @TimWescott, I'll edit the question as well, thank you for pointing out the mixup

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to know if it’s possible to implement 0-delay filters **in real time** ? In which case, the answer is [no](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/47366/63763)

Comment: The technique in the link you provided is only possible in offline processing (or in a block-based real time scenario, but will introduce a delay equal to at least the size of the input block).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your definition of "real time" and how you expect the filter to be used.

Can you implement a two-way, offline IIR filtering scheme like Matlab's `filtfilt` in an embedded system?  Yes, absolutely.

Of necessity, you need to implement it in such a way that *once you are done collecting a segment of data* you can run it on that data *after the fact*.

So if you define "real time" as "for every filter input sample I immediately have a filter output sample" -- no, you can't do that.  You cannot do that because the `filtfilt` function runs a perfectly ordinary filter *forward* through the data from beginning to end, then it runs the same filter *backward* through the data, from end to beginning.  That second step means that you either need a system that sees into the future (that's the "anti-causal" part), or you need to do the filtering retrospectively, on a batch of data that's already been collected (at which point there's a *lot* of delay and phase shift).

But the definition of "real time"  above is not the accepted definition of "real time".

If you define "real time" in the accepted manner -- that all delays are known and guaranteed, and that a system isn't broken *if all promises are met* -- then yes, you can do offline filtering of chunks of data in a real time system.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation and the last part of you answer is precisely what I had in mind that as long as delays are known and guaranteed, it should not be an issue. However, when such block wise processing is being done using IIR filters will the phase between multiple blocks remain maintained or would there be some offsets which would have to be adjusted to maintain coherency?

Comment: That really should be asked as a separate question.  Short answer: if you timestamp things very carefully, the phase between multiple blocks *can be* maintained, with effort.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response, I'll do some work on it and create a new question if and when I get stuck at that part..